# Making new line in php write to file

Tags: php, fwrite

I tried this but wont work

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "Mickey Mouse\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Minnie Mouse\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

This is how it displays in my newfile.txt:

```
Mickey MouseMinnie Mouse`
```

but I want it like this:

```
Mickey Mouse
Minnie Mouse
```

Comment: This is just a `problem` of windows' notepad (or whatever you are using to look into the files). There is a new line, but Notepad does not show it because it wants it in windows style - `\r\n`. Read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline  open your file with a normal text editor (even Wordpad shows it). Or use `\r\n` instead of `\n`, but I would not recommend it. Or, in PHP, PHP_EOL - but universal `\n` is better.

Comment: its working but when i try like this "$ipaddr = "IpAddress:" .$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?:($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']?:$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']).PHP_EOL;" it dosnt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the best to use PHP_EOL. It's cross-platform and will automatically choose the correct newline character(s) for the platform PHP is running on.

```
$txt = "Goofy".PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Note that it's "cross-platform" for the server, not the client that may be reading the newline-delimited file.

Answer (score 1):

\r\n

add the carriage return in front.

Comment: try getting crazy with it  "\r\n\r\n"    does this work?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "Mickey Mouse\n";
 file_put_contents($myFile,$txt ,FILE_APPEND);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

if you want write \n in file use from **file_put_contents($File_Handle,$Text_For_Write,FILE_APPEND)**